# Not able to Set Password and Enable Account using C# and admin User

Tags: c#, active-directory

Using **WPF & C#**, I can set all the attributes in Active Directory, but can't do the following :

1) **Can't Set** User Password

2) **Can't Enable** User

However, I can do the same thing manually!

**Approach Tried:**

1.

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry=

directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {myPass@x6712}); // To set password

directoryEntry.Properties["userAcountControl"].Value=0x0200; //To Enable User
```

2.

```
DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account
```

3.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
  using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName ))
  {
      user.SetPassword( "newpassword" );
      // or
      user.ChangePassword( "oldPassword", "newpassword" );

      user.Save();
  }
}
```

**ERROR ON PASSWORD SET**: Exception has been thrown by the target invocation.

**ERROR ON ENABLE USER**: Access is denied.

**NOTE:** I'm using a Domain Admin User.

The program gives the exception in these above lines.

Please, Advice! Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: As a senior application developer and a member for over a year, you would think to post a stack trace? Please [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) the help center and review the links. `Nothing Helped! the program gives the exception in these above lines`, what is this exception, I don't see one. Could you please update your post to *include relevant information* for us to help you, otherwise we are of no help, thanks.

Comment: `Exception has been thrown by the target invocation` this error is because of the `invoke` on this line: `directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {myPass@x6712});`... With this kind of error, I know for a fact you will have a stack trace that will tell us more about this error. Also, it sounds like the current user doesn't have the privilege to do so, have you tried setting the execution level of the application? For example in Application Manifest File: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`...

Comment: Yes! Execution level is "requireAdministrator" also tried with the "highestAvailable"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is just a mistake in your question, but the code you show in your first example wouldn't compile because the password is not in quotes. It should be:

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {"myPass@x6712"});
```

That code invokes [`IADsUser.SetPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-setpassword). The ['Remarks' in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-setpassword#remarks) point to some prerequisites for it to work, namely, that it must be a secure connection. So it may have failed in setting up a secure connection. It would usually try Kerberos to do that, so something might have gone wrong there.

You can try specifically connecting via LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) by pointing it at port 636 (`new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com:636/CN=whatever,DC=example,DC=com")`), but that requires that you trust the certificate that is served up. Sometimes it's a self-signed cert, so you would need to add the cert to the trusted certs on whichever computer you run this from.

Or, the account you are running it with does not have the 'Reset Password' permission on the account.

For enabling, the [`userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) attribute is a bit flag, so you don't want to set it to `2`, mostly because `2` (or more accurately, the *second bit*) means that it's disabled. So you want to *unset the second bit*. You would do that like this:

```
directoryEntry.Properties["userAcountControl"].Value =
    (int) directoryEntry.Properties["userAcountControl"].Value & ~2;
```

Most of the time that will result in a value of `512` (`NORMAL_ACCOUNT`), but not necessarily. The account could have other bits set that you don't want to inadvertently unset.

You also need to call [`.CommitChanges()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.commitchanges) for the changes to `userAcountControl` to take effect:

```
directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: m doing all accept a 'Secure Connection! How this impacts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: There is no secure communication while trying to set password! As u mentioned m doing the rest things.